# The diagonal of a symmetric matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be a symmetric matrix. Prove that the diagonal of $A$ is in row space of $A$.

Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: It is (to me) an interesting problem.  Have you not tried to solve this yourself before asking for help?

Comment: @hardmath honestly no, it was too hard for me to guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the diagonal of $A$ is zero then we are done. Let's prove the result by induction on $n$ (the order of $A$). If $n=1$ the result is trivial. 
Let's assume wlog that $a_{11}=1$.

Let $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\ldots&0\\
a_{21} & 1 & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1}&0&\ldots & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Note that 
$BA=\begin{pmatrix}1&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\
0 & a_{22}+a_{21}a_{12} & \ldots & a_{2n}+a_{21}a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & a_{n2}+a_{n1}a_{12} &\ldots & a_{nn}+a_{n1}a_{1n}\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, notice that the submatrix 
$C_{n-1\times n-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{22}+a_{21}a_{12} & \ldots & a_{2n}+a_{21}a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n2}+a_{n1}a_{12} &\ldots & a_{nn}+a_{n1}a_{1n}\end{pmatrix}$ is also symmetric, since $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$.

By induction hypothesis, there is $x\in\mathbb{Z}_2^{n-1}$ such that $x^tC=\text{diagonal}(C)=(a_{22}+a_{21}a_{12},\ldots,a_{nn}+a_{n1}a_{1n})$.

Next, since $a_{j1}=a_{1j}$ then $a_{j1}a_{1j}=a_{1j}^2=a_{1j}$.

Hence, $(0,x^t)BA=(0,a_{22}+a_{12},\ldots,a_{nn}+a_{1n})=\text{diagonal}(A)+\text{first row of }A$.

So there is $v\in\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ $(v^t=(0,x^t)B)$ such that $v^tA=\text{diagonal}(A)+\text{first row of }A$. Therefore the diagonal of $A$ belongs to the row space of $A$.