# Prove there exists vector $y\in \mathbb{Z}_2^n \ s.t. Ay=(a_{11},a_{22},\dots,a_{nn})^t.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

> Let $A\in\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be a symmetric matrix. Prove there exists vector $y\in \mathbb{Z}_2^n \ s.t. Ay=(a_{11},a_{22},\dots,a_{nn})^t.$

So I tried some numerical examples and playing with the system of linear equations that comes out of the multiplication, but couldn't find a generalized solution.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that all the entries of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$. Can you proceed after this, using the theory of solution of simultaneous equation?

Comment: @user300 Yes, I know that. What theory do you mean?

Comment: This question was asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748169/the-diagonal-of-a-symmetric-matrix-a-in-m-n-mathbbz-2/1748408#1748408